# Compile freeswitch on debian8, displaying ./.lib/libfreeswitch.so: undefined reference to `vpx_img_alloc'

Tags: freeswitch

I followed the instructions on page https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/FreeSWITCH+1.6+Video to build freeswitch.

And I download and make && make install libyuv and libvpx.

But when I make freeswtich, it display the error messages:
./.lib/libfreeswitch.so: undefined reference to `vpx_img_alloc'
./.lib/libfreeswitch.so: undefined reference to`vpx_img_flip'
./.lib/libfreeswitch.so: undefined reference to `vpx_img_set_rect'
./.lib/libfreeswitch.so: undefined reference to`vpx_img_free'
./.lib/libfreeswitch.so: undefined reference to `vpx_img_wrap'

Why?

Answer (score 1):

FreeSWITCH 1.6 Video dependencies are now packaged for Debian Jessie, you don't have to download and compile yourself, please make sure you're following the steps exactly how they are described.

1. Setup the debian repo:

   ```
   echo "deb http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/debian/ jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/99FreeSWITCH.test.list
   wget -O - http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/debian/key.gpg |apt-key add -
   apt-get update
   ```
2. Install the deps:

   ```
   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=none APT_LISTCHANGES_FRONTEND=none apt-get install -y --force-yes freeswitch-video-deps-most
   ```
3. Checkout and compile (make sure to do a new checkout if you already have done this before):

   ```
   git clone https://freeswitch.org/stash/scm/fs/freeswitch.git freeswitch.git
   cd freeswitch.git
   ./bootstrap.sh -j
   ./configure -C
   ```

Follow the next steps here https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/FreeSWITCH+1.6+Video#FreeSWITCH1.6Video-Compiling

Comment: I had fllowed the step that https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/FreeSWITCH+1.6+Video#FreeSWITCH1.6Video-Compiling before. it can not work.